# Numbers giving a `can’t be used as a single value` error

Tags: numbers

I have a table of data, I am using the following formula `=ROUNDUP(Salary::Table 1::G2:BC5/6,0)`

Error : The range `Salary::Table 1::G2:BC5` can’t be used as a single value.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Are you trying to round up the SUM of `G2:BC5` or round up each individual amount in each cell?

Answer (score 1):

The roundup function needs to be applied to each of the values in the range you give,

Or, you need to use vlookup() for example to extract the particular value from that range and then apply the roundup function.

Comment: Do you man Roundup(Vlookup(range)/6,0) ?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to include the correct arguments for vlookup.